# Problema para retornar mensagem de email invalido e senha invalida

Tags: php

Boa noite,

estou aprendendo PHP PDO, e estou criando um sistema básico, onde tenho a pagina login para verificar se o usuário existe, se existir ele redireciona para a pagina index onde cria uma sessão.
até esse ponto está ok, o meu problema está em quando coloca senha errada ou email errado, fiz uma condição para verificar porem não está funcionando, quando coloco a senha errada mostra a mensagem de senha errada porem quando coloco o email errado ele mostra a mesma mensagem de senha errada, alguém poderia me dar um luz por favor já estou a uns três dias nisso e não consigo sair da pagina login.

segue o código:

```
 <?php  

session_start();
include "conexao.php";
$cliente_email=$_POST['cliente_email'];
$cliente_senha=$_POST['cliente_senha'];

$pdo=conectar();


    $buscar_cliente=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE EMAIL_USUARIO=:email AND SENHA_USUARIO=:senha");
    $buscar_cliente->bindValue(":email",$cliente_email);
    $buscar_cliente->bindValue(":senha",$cliente_senha);
    $buscar_cliente->execute();
    $validar_cliente = $buscar_cliente->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    if($cliente_email == $validar_cliente['EMAIL_USUARIO'] AND $cliente_senha == $validar_cliente['SENHA_USUARIO']):

          $_SESSION['EMAIL_USUARIO'] = $cliente_email;
          $_SESSION['SENHA_USUARIO'] = $cliente_senha;
          header('location:index.php');


    else:

        if($validar_cliente['EMAIL_USUARIO'] = 0 ):
                unset($_SESSION['EMAIL_USUARIO']);
                unset($_SESSION['SENHA_USUARIO']);
                header('location:login.php?area=naoemail');



        else:

            unset($_SESSION['EMAIL_USUARIO']);
            unset($_SESSION['SENHA_USUARIO']);
            header('location:login.php?area=naosenha');
        endif;
    endif;

?>
```

desde já agradeço.

Comment: Faz o seguinte, coloca um var_dump($validar_cliente) em baixo de $validar_cliente = .., e verifica se $validar_cliente['EMAIL_USUARIO'] realmente está vindo com o valor 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal consegui resolver, depois de varias tentativas diferente descobri onde estava meu erro.
eu não parava o laço depois que ele terminava a execução, com isso ele continuava mesmo que validasse o if, foi preciso só colocar um break que ele para, segue o meu código corrigido.

session_start();
include "conexao.php";
$cliente_email=trim($_POST['cliente_email']);
$cliente_senha=$_POST['cliente_senha'];

$pdo=conectar();

```
$buscar_cliente=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE EMAIL_USUARIO=:email");
$buscar_cliente->bindValue(":email",$cliente_email);
$buscar_cliente->execute();
$validar_cliente = $buscar_cliente->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



if($cliente_email != $validar_cliente['EMAIL_USUARIO']):


        unset($_SESSION['EMAIL_USUARIO']);
        unset($_SESSION['SENHA_USUARIO']);
        header('location:login.php?area=naoemail'); 
        break;

else:

    $email_valido = $validar_cliente['EMAIL_USUARIO'];

endif;

var_dump($email_valido);

$buscar_cliente_senha=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE EMAIL_USUARIO=:email");
$buscar_cliente_senha->bindValue(":email",$cliente_email);
$buscar_cliente_senha->execute();
$validar_cliente_senha = $buscar_cliente_senha->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$senha_valida = $validar_cliente_senha["SENHA_USUARIO"];

var_dump($senha_valida);
var_dump($cliente_senha);

if ($senha_valida != $cliente_senha):
     unset($_SESSION['EMAIL_USUARIO']);
    unset($_SESSION['SENHA_USUARIO']);
    header('location:login.php?area=naosenha');
    break;
else:

    $_SESSION['EMAIL_USUARIO'] = $email_valido;
    $_SESSION['SENHA_USUARIO'] = $senha_valida;
    header('location:index.php');




endif;
```

esse é diferente do que eu fiz mas testei no primeiro e deu certo também, agora quando coloco um email que não existe ele me da a mensagem de email invalido, e quando coloco um email valido e uma senha invalida ele retorna a mensagem de senha invalida.

MUito obrigado pela ajuda pessoal vlw mesmo e uma boa noite. PS. Agora eu consigo dormir sussegado.

Answer (score 0):

O que esta acontecendo é o seguinte, ao passar um email ou usuário errado, o mesmo não vai existir no banco de dados, logo, não vai haver dados em `$validar_cliente`, por isso as comparações não dão certo, para corrigir, verifique se existe algo na consulta, ou dê o erro.

> Por conveniência e questão de segurança, não é uma boa prática devolver ao usuário se ele errou o e-mail ou a senha, pois pode facilitar a vida de um invasor.

Para resolver, sem identificar se foi a senha ou o e-mail:

```
<?php  

session_start();
include "conexao.php";
$cliente_email=$_POST['cliente_email'];
$cliente_senha=$_POST['cliente_senha'];

$pdo=conectar();


$buscar_cliente=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE EMAIL_USUARIO=:email AND SENHA_USUARIO=:senha");
$buscar_cliente->bindValue(":email",$cliente_email);
$buscar_cliente->bindValue(":senha",$cliente_senha);
$buscar_cliente->execute();
$validar_cliente = $buscar_cliente->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$quantidade_cliente = count(validar_cliente);

if($validar_cliente):

      $_SESSION['EMAIL_USUARIO'] = $cliente_email;
      $_SESSION['SENHA_USUARIO'] = $cliente_senha;
      header('location:index.php');


else:

        unset($_SESSION['EMAIL_USUARIO']);
        unset($_SESSION['SENHA_USUARIO']);
        header('location:login.php?area=loginerrado');

endif;
```

?>

Agora, para saber se foi a senha ou o e-mail, precisa fazer algumas coisas a mais:

```
<?php  

session_start();
include "conexao.php";
$cliente_email=$_POST['cliente_email'];
$cliente_senha=$_POST['cliente_senha'];

$pdo=conectar();


$buscar_cliente=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE EMAIL_USUARIO=:email AND SENHA_USUARIO=:senha");
$buscar_cliente->bindValue(":email",$cliente_email);
$buscar_cliente->bindValue(":senha",$cliente_senha);
$buscar_cliente->execute();
$validar_cliente = $buscar_cliente->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($validar_cliente):

      $_SESSION['EMAIL_USUARIO'] = $cliente_email;
      $_SESSION['SENHA_USUARIO'] = $cliente_senha;
      header('location:index.php');


else:
        $buscar_erro=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE EMAIL_USUARIO=:email OR SENHA_USUARIO=:senha");
        $buscar_erro->bindValue(":email",$cliente_email);
        $buscar_erro->bindValue(":senha",$cliente_senha);
        $buscar_erro->execute();
        $validar_erro = $buscar_erro->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $rs = '';
        foreach($validar_erro as $erro){
            if($erro['EMAIL_USUARIO'] != $cliente_email){
                $rs = 'email';
                break;
            }elseif($erro['SENHA_USUARIO'] != $cliente_senha){
                $rs = 'senha';
                break;
            }else{
                $rs = 'nenhum';
                break;
            }
        }


        if($rs == 'senha'){

            unset($_SESSION['EMAIL_USUARIO']);
            unset($_SESSION['SENHA_USUARIO']);
            header('location:login.php?area=senha');
        }elseif($rs == 'email'){

            unset($_SESSION['EMAIL_USUARIO']);
            unset($_SESSION['SENHA_USUARIO']);
            header('location:login.php?area=email');
        }elseif($rs == 'nenhum'){

            unset($_SESSION['EMAIL_USUARIO']);
            unset($_SESSION['SENHA_USUARIO']);
            header('location:login.php?area=loginerrado');
        }else{

            unset($_SESSION['EMAIL_USUARIO']);
            unset($_SESSION['SENHA_USUARIO']);
            header('location:login.php?area=naoidentificado');
        }

endif;
```

?>

Até tentei pensar em uma solução melhor pra essa opção, mas infelizmente agora não consegui pensar em nada.

Comment: Eu usei essa correção ai ele só jogava para a pagina naoidentificado a vi que estava procurando igualdade == ai mudei para !=, quando coloco o email errado ele mostra a mensagem email invalido mas quando coloco um email que existe e uma senha errada aparece a mesma mensagem

Comment: @karlosFist da um var_dump($validar_cliente) antes do if para comparar a senha e o email, e coloca o resultado na sua pergunta

Comment: eu usei três var_dump,
var_dump($validar_cliente);
var_dump($validar_cliente['EMAIL_USUARIO']);
var_dump($validar_cliente['SENHA_USUARIO']);
 e me retornou
C:\wamp64\www\Projeto001.01\sessao.php:18:boolean false
C:\wamp64\www\Projeto001.01\sessao.php:19:null
C:\wamp64\www\Projeto001.01\sessao.php:20:null

Comment: Beleza, ja sei o problema, vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: agora qual quer senha ou email que eu colocar ele joga para o index e cria sessão, até para dados não cadastrado no banco

Comment: veja se está vindo um número em $quantidade_cliente ou alguma outra coisa, comenta aqui dai

Comment: está retornado 1, para qual quer email que eu colocar retorna 1

Comment: eu percebi que ali onde busca o erro está assim $validar_erro = $buscar_cliente->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); porem mesmo mudando para $validar_erro = $buscar_erro->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ainda continua do mesmo jeito, também tentei mudar a linha  if($quantidade_cliente == 1): para  $cliente_email == $validar_cliente['EMAIL_USUARIO'] AND $cliente_senha == $validar_cliente['SENHA_USUARIO'], ai só loga quando realmente bate a senha e email, porem quando coloco errado ele pula direto para o ultimo else, do mesmo jeito que estava antes

Comment: da um var dump em validar_cliente, mas sem colocar os nomes, só colocar var_dump($validar_cliente), o problema esta nesse cara

Comment: quando uso um email e senha valido me retorna um array com os dados, quando coloco um email ou senha que não existe retorna false

Comment: Da um olhada no segundo exemplo agr

Comment: se eu colocar um email que existe com uma senha que não existe da um erro no php  Warning: Illegal string offset 'EMAIL_USUARIO' in C:\wamp64\www\Projeto001.01\sessao.php on line 33
agora se eu colocar um email que não existe ele pula para o último else

Comment: Coloque os breaks igual ta ali, ta indo de pouco em pouco pq n to tendo onde testar agora, o que que tem na linha 33 ?